# TypeScript: How to write a function with conditional return type

Tags: typescript

```
export type Name = { name: string }
export type Id = { id: number }
export type Value<T> = T extends string ? Name : Id

export function create<T extends string | number>(value: T): Value<T> {
    if (typeof value === "string") return { name: value }

    return { id: value }
}
```

I am playing around with the conditional types in TypeScript. i would like to write a function with a conditional return type. If the function gets passed a string it returns a Name otherwise it returns an Id.

I get the following error on my return statements:

```
Type '{ name: T & string; }' is not assignable to type 'Value<T>'.
```

What am I missing? Thnx!

Edit: The example taken directly from Anders Hejlsberg talk at Build 2018:
https://youtu.be/hDACN-BGvI8?t=2241

He even states "we do not have to write function overloads anymore..."

If I change the code to just a declaration, the compile errors go away:

```
export type Name = { name: string }
export type Id = { id: number }

export type Value<T> = T extends string ? Name : Id

declare function create<T extends string | number>(value: T): Value<T>

const a = create("Bob")     // a : Name
const b = create(5)         // b : Id
```

So we can declare the function signature. I guess my question then becomes, how would we actually implement the function?

Comment: Is it still state of the art either to overload the function or to "cast" the return values?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is inside the function `T` is not known, so you can't really assign a value to `Value<T>`. One option would be to use a type assertion. A more type safe option would be to use a separate implementation signature, that would be more relaxed about the input and output type:

```
export function create<T extends string | number>(value: T): Value<T> // public signature
export function create(value: string | number): Name | Id { // more relaxed private implementation signature 
    if (typeof value === "string") return { name: value }

    return { id: value }
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution. I just don't see that we gain anything compared to using just two plain overloads?

Comment: You get one overload less … not much advantage here for sure, if you add more it might be worth while ..

Comment: @titan cernicova-dragomir I'm so confused as to why `T` is not known inside the function, even though we eliminate the possibilities. I'm having a lot of trouble understanding this.

How to make sure the public will receive the first signature BTW?

Comment: wow, can't believe this worked...

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it's no better than all the separate overloads and actually harder to read. Within the function, you can still return the wrong type for the condition and you won't get an error. The point of trying to using generics is that you want the return type narrowed based on your conditional.

Comment: @spikyjt It works better with unions than overloads do. Conditional types often require type assertions in the implementation. I do agree with you though, overloads are probably a better solution in this case

Answer (score 13):

Here is another solution which works great as well.

I like this solution better than the accepted answer **because you will get correct type deduction when coding**:

[image]

You can see when hovering, it correctly deduced the type.

Here is the code from the screenshot:

```
export type Name = { name: string }
export type Id = { id: number }
export type Value<T extends string | number> = T extends string ? Name : Id

export function create<T extends string | number>(value: T): Value<T> {
    if (typeof value === 'string') return { name: value } as unknown as Value<T>

    return { id: value } as unknown as Value<T>
}
```

Comment: That's a great solution, although there is no need to type cast to `unknown` then `Value<T>` ; you can directly type cast to `Value<T>`

Comment: FWIW the accepted solution also returns the correct type depending on the input.

Comment: Why do you actually need to cast to `Value<T>`? I've applied this pattern in my case as well, and indeed TS complains that it cannot assign my return type to my conditional type Value<T>, only if I cast it explicitly with `as Value<T>` the problem is gone. Why does it not work without the casting??

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand your example fully, but I think this is what you want?

```
type Name = { name: string }
type Id = { id: number }
type Value = Name | Id

export function create(value: string | number): Value {
  if (typeof value === "string") return { name: value }
  return { id: value }
}
```

See, that I've removed any generics from your example, since I don't see the need for them in this case

Comment: The problem is that with your version  `create(0)` returns `Name | Id` instead of `Id` as expected.

Comment: This would be fine with a couple of overloads. However, my understanding was that conditional types could replace overloads...