# Typescript: how to implement a callable type with a conditional return type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How to implement interface `Foo` when it has a conditional type as its return type?

```
interface Foo {
    <A, B>(a: A, b: B): A extends B ? string : number
}

const foo: Foo = (a, b) => a === b ? 'str' : 123
```

Compiler produces this error:

`Type '"str" | 123' is not assignable to type 'A extends B ? string : number'.
  Type '"str"' is not assignable to type 'A extends B ? string : number'.`

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CA%2C%20B%3E(a%3A%20A%2C%20b%3A%20B)%3A%20A%20extends%20B%20%3F%20string%20%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo%3A%20Foo%20%3D%20(a%2C%20b)%20%3D%3E%20a%20%3D%3D%3D%20b%20%3F%20'str'%20%3A%20123)

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642020/typescript-how-to-write-a-function-with-conditional-return-type) question but I can't see how to translate it to my example. Also, I wonder what is the official/correct approach, in contrast to workarounds.

UPD: I solved it like in the mentioned question, but Unional's answer really helped me to understand the problem. I solved it like this:

```
interface Foo {
    <A, B>(a: A, b: B): A extends B ? string : number
    <A, B>(a: A, b: B): string | number
}
```

Comment: Just post an answer, see if that helps. If you are looking for actual implementation detail, I would suggest defining the type along with the implementation.

Since your implementation is dummy code, I can't help you to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @unional Hi and thank you so much! I am digesting your answer. Even if my implementation is dummy code, It still basically is the same as real one, but simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your type definition is fine.

The problem is that you seem to rely on the type system to guide your development a bit too much.

Since you separate your type definition and your implementation, the compiler naturally looks at them differently.

In a case like this, feel free to cast your implementation to `any`.

The error you saw is because of type inference creates the type `(a: any, b: any) => "str" | 123` for your implementation.

Thus the compiler complains as that type cannot satisfy the type you defined in `Foo`.

Without additional information, that's the best the compiler can do.

Of course, as you implement your code, it is likely that the type inferred by the compiler will eventually satisfy the type you defined.

But remember the main purpose of using TypeScript is to provide information to consume the code you wrote. Using the type to aid implementation is nice but that should be treated as a bonus.

The compiler is not perfect, you are the only one who truly knows your intent.

That's why at times if you need to use `any` to get things going, use it (always with cautions of course).

This shows your type is working:

```
interface B { x: string }

interface A extends B { }

let a: A
let b: B
let c: string
const y = foo(a, b)  // y is string
const x = foo(c, b)  // x is number
```

Remember to write unit tests to prove your implementation.
Type can help you to avoid a class of errors, but not all errors.

UPDATE: As of TypeScript 3.2, I don't think control flow analysis (type inference) can infer conditional type.

Comment: Everything seems to make sense. Thank you! However, I didn't follow your advice about using `any`, and I try to avoid this practice as much as I can. What I did is adding an overload with a union as its return type.

Comment: Added an update: As of TypeScript 3.2, I don't think control flow analysis (type inference) can infer conditional type.

Comment: I try to avoid `any` as much as possible too. Make sure your union overload makes sense to the consumer.

That sounds like a leaky type (the implementation affects the prescribed behavior. It should be the other way around).

Comment: No actually it works perfectly. The important part is to add an overload with a union *after* the original call signature (with the conditional report type). So that typescript picks first from the top overload for function calls and picks the second one to apply it to the implementation. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642020/typescript-how-to-write-a-function-with-conditional-return-type

Comment: That is what I mean leaky. You use the conditional type to narrowed your return type, but then widen it again with the union overload. Your consumers do not need the overload signature. The conditional type one sufficiently described all of the outcomes your code should produce.