# Value not assignable to conditional type while assignable to each type individually

Tags: typescript, types, conditional-types

I have a function with a boolean type parameter to toggle, whether the returned type is some "base" or "derived" type. Now, in the body I always return an instance of derived type, which is certainly assignable to the base type (in the example below, I an write `let val2: Base = val;`, without error). However I still get the error, that `Type 'Derived' is not assignable to type 'V extends true ? Derived : Base'.`

```
interface Base {
  base: number;
}

interface Derived extends Base {
  derived: number;
}

function fun<V extends boolean>(): V extends true ? Derived : Base {
  let val: Derived = {
    base: 0,
    derived: 0
  };
  return val; // error appearing here
}
```

Why is that and how could I make that work?

---

I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57705340/type-is-not-assignable-to-conditional-type) post and read the [article](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) linked in the accepted answer but could not answer my question with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can still pass types other than `true/false`, e.g. `fun<never>` gives `never`, and `Derived|Base` is not assignable to `never`. So you can explicitly cast return type to suppress the TS error

```
function fun<V extends boolean>(): V extends true ? Derived : Base {
  let val: Derived = {
    base: 0,
    derived: 0
  };
  return val as V extends true ? Derived : Base;
}
```

Comment: As far as I know using a type of `never` would be invalid in any case - that's why it's called `never`. Also, even if `V` was `never`, `V extends true` would then still be `false` causing `Base` to be the result of the conditional type.

Comment: The thing is that "V extends true ? Derived : Base" could result in "never", and I don't get what you said about "never" is not a valid type.

Comment: how could `V extends true ? Derived : Base` result in `never`? It's either `Derived` or `Base`. To be fair, not "valid" was not the right word indeed. I'll take that back.

Comment: it is "never", so it is neither Derived nor Base.

Comment: I do not see why you'd think that. Under what circumstances would `V extends true ? Derived : Base` evaluate to `never`?

Comment: when V is never, V extends true ? Derived : Base evaluate to never

Comment: Just tested that and turns out you're right - that seriously surprises me :o Does that mean, whenever I assign to some type parameter (or type depending on one) I need to assert its type explicitly, because it (the type parameter) _may be_ `never`?