# How to declare return type based on parameter's type in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to infer a return type based on the parameter's type.

Here is my try

```
type Arg = string | (() => string)

function fn1(arg: Arg): typeof arg extends Function ? () => string : string {
  if (typeof arg === "function") {
    return () => arg();
  }

  return arg;
}

const a = fn1("hello") // a should be "string"
const b = fn1(() => "hello") // b should be () => "string"
```

[Link to demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcygXigZ2HAlgOyQHygAoiBKFAPnU1wVIFgAoJgMwFccBjYLAexygscARiIBDRAC5YiUtNCReLKBKQQAHsAg4AJmmLlkVDNjxQA-AcrVTSaSdpQA3kyhQsyogohKViFMioAETsXDz8QeQujG5ucBDAbHACZNaqZADcrlAAvkzZ8YnJfghZjHnMjJz8GCoogiJEQQAWEAA2bbyRUAD0PXVozbxsbTpQAEbQQQ54QUzVOLXj9UKiqUZQLe2d3X0T6EMjY5NWG9M0s1BMQA)

Unfortunately I have no idea why typescript fails on line `return () => arg()` with an error `Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string'` where this line is in a if statement.

Comment: Why not return directly `arg` itself ?

Comment: it's just an example :) in the "real life" the `arg` function gets an argument and does some computations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642020

Comment: What's the purpose of this function? It looks like it's having a crisis of identity. Why not just make two functions:  `type FxnA = (string) => string;` and `type FxnB = (Function) => Function`. Then your `typeof` check can be pulled outside of those functions before they are called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature):

```
function fn1(arg: string): string;
function fn1(arg: () => string): () => string;
function fn1(arg: string | (() => string)){
  if (typeof arg === 'function'){
    return () => arg();
  }
  return arg;
}

const a = fn1("hello");
const b = fn1(() => "hello");
```

[Link to demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMMBGAFAQwE4HMBciAzlNjGLgJSElkUDcAsAFCiSwLJpZ6HqWIAvAD5ipclT4CRYuriatw0eEhQYcBWRMQAfROn5DRtCZUoBvFokQxg+qAE8ADgFM4djUMGDEAcjbKCL4WVtaI2C5QINhIhjIa-ArWAL6hEVExiBoKqcwsEAgkWUJcGABEABYuADbVcGWUCgVgRQBGJWoG0qKVNXUNCkA).

Comment: Example 2 does not work. `c` and `d` should call `fn2`.

Comment: @Nenad my bad. Removed from answer.

Comment: It would be nice to make the 2nd example work, but for some reason it doesn't work. If you constrain return type of the function, then you get error in the function body - return type not matching.